# How to get jQuery element custom value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to do a validation. In which i decide to add the error message and validation true or false, even the validation function for the element in the element itself.

```
 _.each(this.bindings, function(keys, index) {
                var element = this.$('#'+index); //i am getting element
                if(keys.validate && keys.validate === true) {
                    element.validate = true; //i am setting attributes works
                    element.errorMessage = "user name must" //this too works
                }

                element.on('focus',function(){ //it works but i am not get the values what i added.
                    console.log(this.errorMessage); //consoles as undefined..how to fix?
                })

        })
```

how can i add the methods, attributes to element itself and call it when i need. I have 50 pages of validation. so i don't want to work for separately.

I do my own validation, don't recommend me a plugin.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried putting focus event outside loop.

Comment: you should put everything in a function, then assign it to the element like this: `$('#myElement').data('myFunction',createdFunctionName())`

Comment: I believe may that would work. but using loop will save me a lot. But I didn't try the one what you say

Comment: @AminJafari, I not clear with your commenet. can you give me some detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the element reference, inside the loop `element` refers to a jQuery object to which you are adding the new properties, but inside the event handler `this` refers to the dom element which does not have the new properties you have added.

```
_.each(this.bindings, function (keys, index) {
    var element = this.$('#' + index); //i am getting element
    if (keys.validate && keys.validate === true) {
        //here element is a jQuery object not a dom element reference so
        element[0].validate = true; //i am setting attributes works
        element[0].errorMessage = "user name must" //this too works
    }

    element.on('focus', function () { //it works but i am not get the values what i added.
        console.log(this.errorMessage); //consoles as undefined..how to fix?
        //here this is dom element reference
    })

})
```

or use the closure variable `element` in the event handler

```
_.each(this.bindings, function (keys, index) {
    var element = this.$('#' + index); //i am getting element
    if (keys.validate && keys.validate === true) {
        //here element is a jQuery object not a dom element reference
        element.validate = true; //i am setting attributes works
        element.errorMessage = "user name must" //this too works
    }

    element.on('focus', function () { //it works but i am not get the values what i added.
        console.log(element.errorMessage); //consoles as undefined..how to fix?
        //here this is dom element reference so use the closure variable element to obtain the newly added properties
    })

})
```

Comment: @3gwebtrain can you try `element[0].errorMessage` in the first sample... also log `console.log(element[0])`

Comment: the second method seems works. and how can i add the listener to this, on foucs, blur..? same as other methods?

Comment: how can i ask to make a call, always, let my element became enable state?

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery.data() -method:

```
_.each(this.bindings, function(keys, index) {
                var element = $('#'+index); //i am getting element
                if(keys.validate && keys.validate === true) {
                    element.data('validate', true); //i am setting attributes works
                    element.data('errorMessage', 'user name must') //this too works
                }

                element.on('focus',function(){ //it works but i am not get the values what i added.
                    console.log(this.data('errorMessage')); //consoles as undefined..how to fix?
                })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use .bind instead of .on:

```
_.each(this.bindings, function(keys, index) {
                var element = this.$('#'+index); //i am getting element
                if(keys.validate && keys.validate === true) {
                    element.validate = true; //i am setting attributes works
                    element.errorMessage = "user name must" //this too works
                }

                element.bind('focus',function(){ //it works but i am not get the values what i added.
                    console.log(this.errorMessage); //consoles as undefined..how to fix?
                })

        })
```